# BootStrap Modal Incorrect Display

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I revamped the UI of my page, such that there's an image and a floating div on the centre of the image.
The div has the button that opens the modal (Bootstrap 3.3.7). 
When I click the button everything appears greyed out, and the modal opens but inside the div and can neither be seen full or closed.
Here are screenshots of the same ( can't include full page because of privacy and security issues)

[image]
[image]

Here is the CSS for the div:

```
.card {
            /* For Shadow Effect*/
            box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
            transition: 0.3s;
            /* Diemensions */
            padding: 5px;
            width: 400px;
            height: 159px;
            text-align: center;
            border-radius: 1rem;
            /*making it stick to the centre*/
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 50%;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            /* randome stuff*/
            background: #CFD8DC;
            margin: auto;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `z-index` property of your `.card` class to a value greater than the overlapping black translucent element.

To do a deeper analysis, open the web inspector to dig into your HTML structure and find the overlapping element I mentioned above. Then, in style properties (should be on the right), find the `z-index` property. If you cannot find it, check through its parent elements. If you cannot still find it, you should be able to set an arbitrary value, greater than zero, which should make your page look as you want.

Keep in mind that `z-index` works only if `position` attribute is set to `absolute` or `relative` or `fixed`.

Comment: I edited the `z-index` (set card to 1 and modal 2 ) value but didn't help. I wan't the modal to pop up as wanted, the card is alright.

Comment: You must set a higher value for the front element than the backing one. Did you try to invert `z-index` values?

Comment: I did, nothing happened.